# Is the following proper notation or am I abusing notation too much?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, notation

I am mostly a lazy person and so if I can reduce what I write, all the better. Obviously ultimately it is for the professor to decide whether something is or not an abuse in notation, but I want to know whether this is, at least, acceptable in the general case.

I have made the following statement:

Assume $n\equiv 2 \pmod5$:

Then $n^5\equiv2^5\pmod5 \implies n^5-n\equiv 2^5-2=30\equiv0 \pmod5 \implies n^5-n=5k$

for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$

The part I am unsure about is the equals sign followed by a congruency symbol. It seems to me readable enough, but I am very lax with notation.

Edit:

I know this is not the whole proof to my problem, there are 4 other cases to consider, but it's pretty much copy paste this assumption and change the  numbers, it's explicetly the notation that I am conerned about.

Comment: What are you trying to prove? And yes, that is proper notation.

Comment: That for all $n$, $n^5-n$ = $5k$

Comment: You could just replace the $=$ sign with the $\equiv$ symbol with no effect on your result.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Though the proof is not complete, because you assumed $n \equiv 2 \pmod 5$

Comment: You need to explain for $n\not\equiv2\ (\mod5)$

Comment: All you need is to show it for the 5 equivalent classes . My concern is the notation not the proof.

Comment: Perhaps a more elegant proof would be to show that $n^5-n\equiv n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)\pmod{5}$ and exactly one of those factors is congruent to $0$, so $n^5-n\equiv 0\pmod{5}$

Comment: It’s perfectly fine, because the two quantities flanking the equals sign are in fact one and the same number.

Comment: @Riley perhaps more elegant, but I have no idea how you got the right hand side of that relationship. If you used a theorem then I probably can''t use that result without proving the theorem

Comment: I found the right hand side by factoring $n^5-n$ normally to get $n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)$ then from there I guessed that $n^2+1$ would factor out further because there needs to be a $0$ factor for all $n$. Also note that $(n-1)\equiv (n+4)\pmod{5}$. And even if I used a special theorem to discover this, all you need to prove your result is to multiply out the right hand side and verify that it's congruent to $n^5-n$

Comment: Are you required to use modular arithmetic?  Because there is a simple proof by induction that just uses a binomial expansion. $$\begin{split}0^5-0 & =0 \\ (n+1)^5-(n+1) & = (n^5-n)+5(n^4+2n^3+2n^2+n)\end{split}$$

Comment: @Riley I get up to $n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)\equiv  n(n+4)(n+1)(n^2+1)$ but how are you getting the 2 and 3? $n^2+1$ cannot be factored out "normally" since it has no roots, so i assume you are using modulus arithemtic to be able to factor it out into the other 2 terms

Comment: Yes, $n^2+1$ can't be factored out normally, so this is when we restrict ourselves to the mod world. So what are the solutions to $n^2+1\equiv 0\pmod{5}$ (the roots to $n^2+1$)? Well, adding $4$ to both sides and we have $n^2\equiv 4\pmod{4}$. And $4$ has two square roots: $2$ and $-2$. So $n^2+1\equiv (n+2)(n-2)\equiv (n+2)(n+3)\pmod{5}$.

Alternatively, it is simple to guess that since $2$ and $3$ are the missing roots, we might have $n^2+1\equiv (n-2)(n-3)\equiv (n+2)(n+3)\pmod{5}$. We can easily verify our guess by simply multiplying it out.

Comment: I think you got carried away just a tiny bit, but you can get carried away *a lot* more than that. Figure out a way to work $\iff$ and $\Leftarrow$ in there.